# How to check file exist in path with extension in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-module

I just want to know about how to check the file exists or not any directory via ansible code. I have tried with stat module with path "*.test" already but it did not working.

Below is my trying:

```
- name: Check license file exist or not
  stat:
    path: /var/www/vb_backup/vb/*.test
  register: license
```

becuase **path** in stat module needs specific file or directory. I want everyone to help me on this.

Thank you in advance.

Ansible version: ansible 2.8.7

Answer (score 3):

Use module [find](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html#find-return-a-list-of-files-based-on-specific-criteria). For example

```
  - find:
      paths: /var/www/vb_backup/vb
      patterns: "*.test"
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "No files found."
    when: result.matched == 0

  - debug:
      msg: "File found: {{ item.path }}"
    loop: "{{ result.files }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use find module and assert module.

```
- name: Find files
  find:
    paths: /var/www/vb_backup/vb
    patterns: *.test'
  register: output
- name: message
  assert:
    that:
    - output.matched
    fail_msg: "File not found"
    success_msg: "File found"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work.

```
path: "{{/var/www/vb_backup/vb/*.test}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use find module like this

```
find:
  paths: /var/www/vb_backup/vb/
  patterns: *.test
```

then you can invoke matched files